# R data.frame to function as.function.data.frame

Tags: functional-programming, r

I love relation and function. And I would love to move afap from one to the other.

I've been looking for the function as.function.data.frame (or alike on tbl) but couldn't get it.

*The bells and whistles are not yet present (test, check...)*

```
## returns function
## In some way relation are function
## | p1 | p2 | p3 | value |
## f(p1, p2, p3) = value
## only if functionnal dependency applies
## for a given combination of parameter, value is unique

as.function.data.frame = 
  function(dt, fmla){

    require(dplyr)

    f = as.function(fmla)
    valx = body(f)


    ## enclose data
    f_env = new.env()
    assign('dt', dt, f_env)
    assign('valx', # later used to select the attribute
           f %>% body %>% as.character,
           f_env)
    environment(f) <- f_env

    ## the body
    body(f) <- quote(
      {
        ## the filter: easier to get it as a data.frame and later inner_join, than use the dplyr::filter. imho
        fltr = 
          as.list(match.call())[-1] %>% ## -1 because the call is enclosed and contains on to much element.
          as.data.frame

        fltr %>%
          inner_join(dt, by = names(fltr)) %>%
          select_(valx) %>% ## select_ because a need to evaluate
          unlist %>% unname ## we want value not table (value may be table...)
      }
    )

    return(f)
  }
```

a start of a test

```
library(testthat)
## test it
test_that("test the as.function.data.frame",
          {
            dt_test = 
              data.frame(
                par1 = c(1,1,0,0),
                par2 = c(1,0,1,0),
                val1 = 1:4,
                val2 = 5:8) 

            dt_fun1 = dt_test %>% as.function(par1 + par2 ~ val1)
            dt_fun2 = dt_test %>% as.function(par1 + par2 ~ val2)

            expect_equal(dt_fun1(1,0), 2)
            expect_equal(dt_fun2(0,0), 8)
          }
)
```

Three points:

- Has this function been implemented in an other package? (base, dplyr...)
- Is it an okay way to build the function?
- `as.list(match.call())[-1]`: I am looking for a way to get it like `as.list(match.call())` but without the `[-1]` I get the full function as first argument and then the one I want.